# Issue with Uploaded Images

Tags: media

Alright, I've got an odd issue with what I am guessing to be is size. I have uploaded several images to a site, and while they upload correctly (meaning I can find the image in the appropriate folder without loss of quality), I can't see images larger than what I am guessing is from 400-500KB. As you can see, the two bottom images are 353KB or less in size, and I can see them. However, the upper three are 850KB or larger and cannot be seen, am I doing something wrong with this? Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this happening each time you upload image larger than 800kb?

Comment: Edit this image field check Preview image style set to what measurements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, I just reset and added to the PHP limits in my configuration. After that, worked like a charm.